# All Characters in my Bitmap Textfile are in Chinese

Tags: c#, bitmap, fbx

So I am currently working on a program that will extract materials from .fbm files. In the ASCII fbm files, the data to extracted looks as follows:
`/9j/4Sb7RXhpZgAATU0AKgAAAAgADAEAAAMAAAABEAAAAAEBAAMAAAABEAAAAAECAAMAAAADAAAAngEGAAMAAAABAAIAAAESAAMAAAABAAEAAAEVAAMAAAABAAMAAAEaAAUAAAABAAAApAEbAAUAAAABAAAArAEoAAMAAAABAAIAAAExAAIAAAAiAAAAtAEyAAIAAAAUAAAA1odpAAQAAAABAAAA7AAAASQACAAIAAgACvyAAAAnEAAK/IAAACcQQWRvYmUgUGhvdG9zaG9wIENDIDIwMTcgKFdpbmRvd3MpADIwMTk6MDc6MD`
`...`

And there are several sets of these in the fbm file, each in quotations and comma-separated. Now, when I convert the first one of these strings in the file to a jpg, using the following:

```
                        //Convert ASCII data to binary
                        string asciiFileData = "";
                        StreamReader binaryDataReader = File.OpenText(Path.Combine(inputDirectory, convertedFBX + iterator.ToString() + ".txt"));
                        while (!binaryDataReader.EndOfStream)
                        {
                            var lineData = binaryDataReader.ReadLine();
                            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(lineData)) continue;
                            asciiFileData += lineData;
                        }
                        string[] imageStrings = asciiFileData.Split(',');
                        List<byte[]> imageList = new List<byte[]>();
                        foreach (string imageString in imageStrings)
                        {
                            if(imageString.Length > 10)//A way of checking if there's actual data for the file to save
                                imageList.Add(Convert.FromBase64String(imageString.Trim().Replace(",", "").Replace("\"", "")));
                        }
                        //Save images
                        int iterator2 = 1;
                        foreach(byte[] image in imageList)
                        {
                            File.WriteAllBytes(Path.Combine(inputDirectory, convertedFBX + iterator.ToString() + iterator2++ + ".jpg"), image);
                        }
```

The first string creates a proper jpg of the materials. When I open it up in a text file, it's the usual strange alien characters (not quite positive what those are called). However, the jpgs after the first one cannot open. I open up the text files for them, and all the characters are in Chinese! Why on earth is that happening? What does it mean, and is it supposed to be that way? Thanks in advance for your answers!

Comment: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140930-00/?p=43953. That is to say, do not force the poor text editor to interpret the binary content as if it was a text in a certain encoding. (Semi related, you should probably see https://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html.)

Comment: `StreamReader` is for textual content only. For binary data you should use `BinaryReader`.

Comment: This is great info, @GSerg ! Would you mind putting it into an answer so I can mark this question as answered?

Comment: @silkfire the original content is Base64, so that's correct, actually.

Comment: "However, the jpgs after the first one cannot open." Open them in a _hex editor_ and look up what the start of a jpeg file is _supposed_ to look like. Then you can see what is wrong in your follow-up files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This resource was mentioned in the comments; however, my answer was found at https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140930-00/?p=43953. Essentially, this error is what occurs when you try to force binary content to be some sort of specific encoding that it's not meant to be.